# Bootstrap forms aligning. "form-group row" misplaced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this problem, next "form-group row" misplaced. Working on django/jinja template (flask project).

This code:

```
<div class="row">
<div style="color: chocolate; padding: 10px; margin-left: 10px; font-size: 25px;">Client Details</div>
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 20px 0px 0px;">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="border-left: 5px solid #eee; margin: 0 0 20px;">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="labelbox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Client ID</label>
                <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" col-sm-6 type="text" value="" id="client-id" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn" type="button" data-clipboard-target="client-id">Copy</button>
                    </span
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label id="labelbox" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Client Secret</label>
                <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="client-secret" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn" type="button" data-clipboard-target="client-secret">Copy</button>
                    </span
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This behavior is here: http://www.bootply.com/Ig0ilwpSdh

[image: Safari 10.0.3 Render]

Ideally I would like to have newline, which I could do with 
, but since I'm using bootstrap, I'm thinking everything could be done with just bootstrap.

And also vertically align input fields.

By the way, misplacing appears, when I add:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
```

Can you advice how I should better handle that?